# QNetworkAccessManager issue getting web page

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to download the source code of a web page with the following code in
header file:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QHttp>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

class CDownloader : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit CDownloader(QObject *parent = 0);

void Do_Download();

signals:

public slots:
  void result(QNetworkReply*);
private:   
  QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
  QNetworkReply *reply;
  QNetworkAccessManager qnam;
};

#endif // CDOWNLOADER_H
```

and the source file:

```
#include "cdownloader.h"

CDownloader::CDownloader(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{    
}

void CDownloader::Do_Download()
{
  manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(result(QNetworkReply*)));
  manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com")));
}

void CDownloader::result(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
     qDebug() << "loading complete";
}
```

and on push button code:

```
void MainWindow::on_download_clicked()
{
  CDownloader cDown;
  cDown.Do_Download(); 
}
```

but qDebug is never called in the result slot. What am i missing?

Comment: Your code looks good as far as I can see. Mind posting the complete code?

Comment: @ion There is a memory leak in the code. You must delete the QNetworkReply in your `finished()` handler.  You can use `reply->deleteLater()` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::on_download_clicked()
{
  CDownloader cDown;
  cDown.Do_Download(); 
}
```

When that method returns, `cDown` is immediately destructed. You need to keep that object alive at least as long as you haven't received and processed the reply.

For that, either `cDown` should be a member of your `MainWindow`, or a pointer to (or collection of pointers to) `CDownloader` should be maintained (and properly disposed) somewhere in your code.